# Jersey SecurityContext.getUserPrincipal() returns null for non Singleton Resource

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

My Resource is not a Singleton, at every new Request I can see that my Resource constructor is being called. I am injecting a `@Context SecurityContext` in my constructor and then getting the `Principal` as `securityContext.getUserPrincipal()`.

The problem is, I am building my `SecurityContext` in an `ContainerRequestFilter`, where I get the user from the token inside the `Autorization` header and create a new `SecurityContext`, but the `ContainerRequestFilter` runs **AFTER** the Resource was created, so at construction time the `securityContext.getUserPrincipal()` returns null.

I want to avoid calling `securityContext.getUserPrincipal()` at each one of my Resource's methods, so are there any ways to make the `ContainerRequestFilter` run **BEFORE** the Resource's creation?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `@PreMatching` annotation to the `ContainerRequestFilter` makes it run before the Resource is selected and created by the framework.